# Can I use XPS insulation over poly sheet foundation waterproofing?

Tags: vapor-barrier, basement-insulation

I recently had an internal perimeter French drain to sump installed along with a vapor barrier that directs water down into the French drain. Now I need to frame and get walls up. The piece I am having trouble with is insulation.

My understanding is I don't want to use XPS on top of the vapor barrier because it will create another place for water to form on the warm side of the vapor barrier. This would lead me to think batt insulation is the way to go but I keep reading how not to use batt in basements.

Any ideas what I should do? I believe my basement will now be dry but I live in Michigan and would like it to also be warm in the winter.

Comment: Technically a sump drain circuit isn't a "French drain". French drains exit via gravity to a location downhill but  above grade. Also, the sheeting isn't a "vapor barrier". It's waterproofing--a _liquid_ water barrier.

Comment: How were you thinking of installing the XPS? If it's tight to the poly it's not really a problem--it's only when there's an air gap that condensation can form.